# Initializing end of the string in C

Tags: c, arrays, string

I am learning C now and I'm at the point where I don't really get what is the difference of initializing the end of the string with NULL `'\0'` character. Below is the example from the book:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    int i;
    char str1[] = "String to copy";
    char str2[20];

    for(i = 0; str1[i]; i++)
        str2[i] = str1[i];
    str2[i] = '\0'; //<====WHY ADDING THIS LINE??

    printf("String str2 %s\n\n", str2);

    return 0;
}
```

So, why do I have to add NULL character? Because it works without that line as well. Also, is there a difference if I use:

```
for (i = 0; str1[i]; i++){
    str2[i] = str1[i];
}
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Note: above code shows *bad* indentation, which actively misleads anybody reading the code. This is why `{}` should be always used with `if`, `else`, `do`, `while`, `for` etc. Also auto-indentation performed by IDE/editor/tool which actually understands C is highly recommended (and may alleviate need to use `{}` everywhere).

Comment: I always use curly braces, however this is direct copy from the book, so this is why I decided to leave it as it is, to have exact explanations. Thanks for the tip though.

Comment: Take care to distinguish the "nul character" ('\0') from NULL, which is a totally different thing (a pointer pointing to nothing).

Comment: Code working without adding terminating 0 is pure coincidence. Apparently when you executed the program without that, the `str2` was stored in stack in location which happened to contain zeros (not all that unlikely when program has just started and may have clean stack memory area). But stack variables do not have default initialization of any kind, so this is *undefined behaviour*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C, the end of the string is detected by the null character. Consider the string 'abcd'. If the variable in the actual binary have the next variable immediately after the 'd' character, C will think that the next characters in the platform are part of that string and you will continue. This is called buffer overrun.

Your initial statement allowing 20 bytes for str2 will **usually** fill it with 20 zeroes, However, this is not required and may not occur. Additionally, let us say you move a 15 character string into str2. Since it starts with 20 zeroes, this will work. However, say that you then copy a 10 character string into str2. The remaining 5 characters will be unchanged and you will then have a 15 character string consisting of the new 10 characters, followed by the five characters previously copied in.

In the code above the for loop says move the character in str1 to str2 and point to the next character. If the character now pointed to in str1 is not 0, loop back and do again. Otherwise drop out of the loop. Now add the null character to the end of the str2. If you left that out, the null character at the end of str1 would not be copied to str2, and you would have no null character at the end of str2.

This can be expressed as

```
        i = 0;
label:
        if (str1[i] == 0) goto end;
        str2[i] = str1[i];
        i = i + 1;
        goto label;
 end:   /* This is the end of the loop*/
```

Note that the '\0' character has not yet been moved into str2.

Since C requires brackets to show the range of the for, only the first line after the for is part of the loop. If i had local scope and is lost after the loop, you would not be able to  just wait to fall out of the loop and make it 0. You would no longer have a valid i pointer to tell you where in str2 you need to add the 0.

An example is C++ or some compilers in C which would allow (syntactically)

```
for (int i = 0; str1[i]; i++)
  {
    str2[i] = str1[i];
  }
str2[i] = 0;
```

This would fail because i would be reset to whatever it happened to be before it entered the loop (probably 0) as it falls out of the loop. If it had not been defined before the loop, you would get an undefined variable compiler error.

I see that you fixed the indentation, but had the original indentation stayed there, the following comment would apply.

C does not work solely by indentation (as Python does, for example).  If it did, the logic would be as follows and it would fail because str2 would be overwritten as all 0.

```
for (int i = 0; str1[i]; i++)
  {
    str2[i] = str1[i];
    str2[i] = 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

The line you're referring to is added in general use for safety.  When you copy values to a string you always want to be sure that it's null terminated, otherwise when reading the string it will continue past the point where you want the end of that string to be (because it doesn't know where to stop due to lack of the null terminator).

There is no difference with the alternate code you posted since you are separating only the line below the for statement to be in the loop, which happens by default anyway if you don't use the curly braces {}

Answer (score 0):

'\0' is used for denoting end of string. It is not for the compiler, it is for the libraries and possibly your code. C does not support arrays properly. You can have local arrays, but there is no way to pass them about. If you try you just pass the start address (address of first element). So you can ever have the last element be special e.g. '\0' or always pass the size, being careful not to mess up.

For example:

If your string is like this:

```
char str[]="Hello \0 World";
```

will you tell me what would display if you print `str`  ?
Output is:

```
Hello
```

This will be the case in character arrays, Hence to be in safer side, it is good to add '\0'at the end of string.

If you didnt add '\0', some garbage values might get printed out, and it will keep on printing till it reached '\0'

Answer (score 0):

You should only add a `\0` (also called the null byte) in the end of the string. Do as follows:

```
...

for(i = 0; str1[i]; i++) {
    str2[i] = str1[i];
}

str2[i] = '\0'; //<====WHY ADDING THIS LINE??

...
```

(note that I simply added braces to make the code more readable, it was confusing before)

For me, that is clearer. What you were doing before is basically take advantage of the fact that the integer `i` that you declared is still available after you ran the loop to add a `\0` in the end of `str2`.

The way strings work in C is that they are basically a pointer to the location of the first character and string functions (such as the ones you can find in `string.h`) will read every single char until they find a `\0` (null byte). It is simply a convention for marking the end of the string.

Some further reading: http://www.cs.nyu.edu/courses/spring05/V22.0201-001/c_tutorial/classes/String.html

Answer (score 0):

In C, char[] do not know the length of the  string. It is therefore important character '\0' (ASCII 0) to indicate the end of the string. Your "For" command will not copy '\0', so output is a string > str2 (until found '\ 0' last stop)

Try:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    int i;
    char str[5] = "1234";
    str[4] = '5';
    printf("String %s\n\n", str);
    return 0;
}
```